# Google Maps API 2 for Android "Unfortunately, [app] has stopped."

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I've run through the android developers guide and youtube guides, and I've also checked the other similar questions asked here, but am still unable to load a map on a Nexus 7.

I'm trying to build an application that will later highlight local businesses in my area, but first need to be able to load a map.  Every time I try to run it on a device, it gives the notification of "Unfortunately, [app] has stopped."

here's my code:

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.bloomingtonfirst"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
    android:name="com.example.bloomingtonfirst.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission   
android:name="com.example.bloomingtonfirst.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission       
android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<meta-data
    android:name="come.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="super_secret_key"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.bloomingtonfirst.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

mainactivity.java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

SupportMapFragment mMap;
GoogleMap googleMap;

  @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       mMap = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        googleMap = mMap.getMap();
 }
}
```

logcat:

```
03-19 16:25:55.620: D/dalvikvm(16340): GC_CONCURRENT freed 256K, 6% free 7463K/7864K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 22ms
03-19 16:25:55.660: D/AndroidRuntime(16340): Shutting down VM
03-19 16:25:55.660: W/dalvikvm(16340): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d26930)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bloomingtonfirst/com.example.bloomingtonfirst.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at com.example.bloomingtonfirst.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    ... 11 more
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at maps.z.ab.a(Unknown Source)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at maps.z.ab.a(Unknown Source)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at maps.z.ab.a(Unknown Source)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at maps.z.ag.a(Unknown Source)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at maps.z.ag.a(Unknown Source)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at maps.z.bw.a(Unknown Source)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at maps.z.r.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$Stub.onTransact(IMapFragmentDelegate.java:107)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:310)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.e$4.a(Unknown Source)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.e.a(Unknown Source)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.e.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:884)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1066)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1168)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:280)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
03-19 16:25:55.660: E/AndroidRuntime(16340):    ... 21 more
```

any attempt to help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does the logcat say?

Comment: @RaghavSood added the LogCat, couldn't figure how to format it better though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `android:name="come.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"`
to `android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"` (come to com).

Comment: thank you so much. that was the last problem and I've got it running now.

Comment: I guess there should be a Lint rule to warn you if you use maps v2 and not everything is set properly in the manifest. It is not as easy as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

To:

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

You are getting a ClassCastException as in your code you import `com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment` and use it, but in your XML you use `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment`.

Comment: changed that to SupportMapFragment and updated the LogCat and xml files.  I'm still getting the same "Unfortunately, [app] has stopped" though.

Comment: @dustin your error is different now. You don't have an api key in your app.

Comment: thanks so much for your help. the last bit was a typo and I've got it working now.